# Is GLM appropriate for an extreme unbalanced dataset?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, sample-size

I have a dataset with 174 females and 28 males. I am interested in the gender differences, as well as the interactions between gender and other factors, in a continuous dependent variable. Is GLM appropriate for this very unbalanced dataset? What would be a better alternative?

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Comment: Your question is about GLMs, but the imbalanced variable is an explanatory variable, not a response. It may be quite reasonable to use a standard linear model (ie, assume a normal response). Note that a t-test is a special case of a linear model, which is a special case of a GLM. Moreover, the issue here plays out the same, so although it may not look like it, this is the same question as the linked thread.